# Automatically update marker location and infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am parsing a CSV file and turning lines into markers on a map, with a corresponding button on a sidebar.

My current method for creating markers is

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var sensor, i, latlng;
for (i in sensorList) {
    // Creates a marker
    sensor = sensorList[i];
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(sensor.lat, sensor.lng);
    bounds.extend(latlng);
    var marker = createMarker(
        latlng, sensor.name, sensor.reading
    );  

    // Creates a sidebar for the marker
    createMarkerButton(marker);
}

// Fit to map bounds
mapCanvas.fitBounds(bounds);
```

and my createMarker function is

```
function createMarker(latlng, title, html) {
    // Creates a marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: mapCanvas,
        title: title
});
// The InfoWindow is opened when the sidebar button is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            infoWnd.setContent("<div class = \"PopUp\" style=\"width: 150px; height: 100px;\"<strong>"+title+"</title></strong><br>Latest reading: "+html+"<br><a href=\"\">Full reading</a>");
            infoWnd.open(mapCanvas, marker);
        });
        return marker;
    }
```

This works great with a CSV file where each sensor name/location is unique.
I am trying to expand this to support the same sensor storing multiple entries in the CSV file and only creating a marker/button for the latest entry for each sensor.

I believe the recommended way of doing this is to keep an array of markers, and each time I create a marker I should compare to this array. 
I am quite new to Javascript and Google-Maps and am unsure about exactly where this check should take place. I've toyed around with a few possibilities but none seem to work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First words of advice, as it's not entirely clear to me whether or not your sensorList is an object or an array (I suspect it is an array? as I don't see why it would be an object here), is do not use the "for in" construct on arrays and also do not create associative arrays in javascript. Save the "for in" construct only for objects, and use "for" or "while" or "do while" on arrays. I say this for two reasons, one is that the "for in" loop is actually the slowest of the available types of loops, and secondly for readability obviousness of variable type (you see a "for" or "while" or "do while" loop and you should be able to know you're dealing with an array, likewise you see a "for in" loop you should be able to know you're dealing with an object);

Usually a good way to weed out multiple entries with the same property name is to use an object to store the value of the "sensor" objects name and then check the object for the presence of the same name. For example, say you have an array of objects:

```
var sensorList = [ //an array of objects
    {name: 'sensorA', propA: 1, propB: 2},
    {name: 'sensorB', propA: 3, propB: 4},
    {name: 'sensorC', propA: 5, propB: 6},
    {name: 'sensorB', propA: 7, propB: 8},
    {name: 'sensorA', propA: 9, propB: 10},
    {name: 'sensorD', propA: 11, propB: 12}
];
```

Then create an object which you can use to filter for existing names:

```
var sensorsObj = {};
```

Now loop through sensorList and check for each sensor by name existing already or not in sensorsObj:

```
for (var sensor, i = 0, len = sensorList.length; i < len; i++) {
    sensor = sensorList[i];
    if (!sensorsObj[sensor.name]) {
        sensorsObj[sensor.name] = 1;
        //we know we have not ran across this name yet, so here we can
        //create LatLng's, extend bounds, create markers, yada yada yada
    }
}
```

Now, not sure what the order of things is in your sensorList, oldest to newest or newest to oldest. If oldest to newest, you may want to do: sensorList = sensorList.reverse(); right before the "for" loop to reverse the order of the array. Actually, now that I say that, it would actually be slightly better (quicker) to start the loop from the end of the array instead:

```
for (var sensor, i = sensorList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.

I am pretty new to Javascript and had no idea that for in was much slower, I'll make that change for sure.

Comment: I was over-complicating things by trying to update the markers when really (as you pointed out) I just needed to work my way from the bottom up and ignore repeated sensor names. This works great.